# How to use sed in order to change properties file with paths

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to use `sed` in order to replace some properties in dedicated file with a value that is a path.
I need some how to escape the value itself.

**Example:**

```
property1.key=
property3.key=
```

I used the following sed in order to set property1 with dedicated value.

```
value1=/home/usr/example
sed -i "s/^\(property1\.key\s*=\s*\).*\$/\1\'"$value1"'/" $FILE_NAME
```

The problem is with the "/" which seperate the path in the value.
i'm getting this error message:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 49: unknown option to `s'

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/1096/substitution/12280/using-different-delimiters#t=201703300945404412202

Comment: awsome great refernece!
the trick was to use different delimiter.
i used the "_" instead of the default "/" of sed
thanks